# Vowels with umlaut displayed correctly in SQL SMS but incorrectly in application

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

My application displays an unknown character before vowels with umlaut. So the word "für" would be displayed as "f?ür". However, when I display the record in SQL Server Management Studio, the results are formatted properly.

Database in question has a collation of `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. Extended properties of this DB also show this line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?>
```

My app seems to be encoded with UTF-8.

I tried creating a view out of my table and setting the column collation to

```
CREATE VIEW MY_VIEW 
AS 
     SELECT 
         ID, NAME COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8 NAME
     FROM 
         MY_TABLE
```

However I get back an error saying that specified collation is invalid. Even though intellisense is happy with it.

`NAME` column is of type `varchar(50)`.

My questions are therefore following. I assume that my database is encoded by UTF-16 and the app by UTF-8 and this discrepancy is the culprit. Is that correct? If so, what is the solution? If not, what is the problem and how to solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: *"However I get back an error saying that specified collation is invalid."* UTF-8 collations were added in SQL Server 2019; what version are you using?

Comment: I have a suspicion that the `encoding="utf-16"` is probably describing the encoding *of the XML file*, not of your database.